# Multiple managed metadata tags single document

Tags: 2010, managed-metadata, tagging

I have added a document to my document library.

How do I add **multiple** managed-metadata tags to a single document?

I would like to have functionality similar to the way tags work in stack exchange (e.g. Sharepoint, 2010, managed-metadata and tagging).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to add a Enterprise Metadata field to your document library.

Alternatively you can use a predefined tag list by adding a Managed Metadata field.

Go to the document library in question, select On the ribbon > Library > Library settings

From here you can create new columns.

update: [[source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-a-managed-metadata-column-HA101631602.aspx)]
"In the Multiple Value field section, specify whether you want to allow multiple values in the column. If you allow multiple values, users will not be able to sort on this column in list views."

Comment: With an Enterprise Metadata field, can you use multiple tags? I do have a Managed Metadata field, but it doesn't allow me to enter multiple tags.

Comment: Ryan, there is a checkbox I guess which allows you to give multiple tags... I don't have SharePoint right now, but I have done it using Metadata field :)

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri please use "@Ryan" rather than Ryan so that I know your responded. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @RyanGates no problem!